# CSS: How to make element appear from left of the screen?

Tags: html, css, animation, web

I have a element which I would like it to animate to the right off the screen and then start from the left off the screen. I want it to dissapear off the screen to the right and appears again coming out from the left of the screen. Is there a way I could go about doing this? Here's what I have so far. With my code, it animates to the right off the screen but then the elements goes backwards to its position point whereas I want it to appear again from the left of the screen. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    .bus { position:absolute; top: 640px; left: 100px; height:150px; width:290px; z-index: 2; 
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s infinite;
    animation: myfirst 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-duration: 10s;

     animation-direction: normal;
      -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

}

    @-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {left: 0%;}

    50%  {left: 100%;}

    100% {left:0%;}
}

@keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {left: 0%;}

    50%  {left: 100%;}

    100% {left:0%;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fairly self explanatory. If you don't want the object to animate back to `0%` omit the line from you animation...

```
@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
```

Demo...

```css
.bus {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 290px;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s infinite;
    animation: myfirst 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    background: red;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bus"></div>
```